# Encrypting/Decrypting a POST form

Tags: php, forms, encryption, post

I'm really new to php so what's happening is that I have a form which has an action of 'email_form.php'.  CLicking the submit button takes the user to 'email_form.php' which processes the information (it looks something like below);

```
<?php
$to = "email";

$subject = "rego form";

$ message = "Name: " . $_REQUIRE['Title'] . "\r\n" .

.
.
.

RE['CancellationPolicyAgreement'];

$from = $_REQUIRE['Email'];

$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n";

$headers = "Bcc: email" . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

`

Something like that.  So my question is - how do I encrypt the form content?  Obviously I've cut out some fields, but it does include credit card details and that's not something I'd want anybody else to get.

If anybody could give me a simple, layman-term explanation that would be really REALLY appreciated!!!!

Drea

Comment: How it is supposed to decrypt it back?

Comment: I would really advise against sending credit card details by e-mail.
E-mail isn't a secure medium.

Comment: You should be using ssl for the form submission, and you should not be including the card details (unless part blanked card numbers such as ****-****-****-5733 in any email)... and I hope you're not storing card numbers anywhere in your database

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you use a big expensive credit card processing system... HTTPS, secure data storage, the works. Otherwise the credit card companies will take away your right to process credit cards, because they demand that level of security.

Or you use a system like PayPal. They'll handle the credit cards for you, and just give you the money (minus a small fee).